# Should I say "He had been crying in 'this' / 'those' time?"

Tags: prepositions

When I'm talking about the past time that in the past there was someone that he had been crying, what is the right way to express it in the words "in this time" (in the past)?

Is it better to "In those time" because this time we don't see / it's far away from us. Or it doesn't matter whether using of "in this time" or "in those time" in our issue.

Comment: A few things are incongruent.  The "in" seems incorrect.  Could it be perhaps "at"?  Also, "had crying" perhaps ought to be "had cried" or "had been crying"?  Also, 'time' is singular, you can't use "those" with it.

Comment: Just in the title it was mistake when I dropped the "been". I edited it. Thank you

Comment: "He had been crying for minutes/hours at that time." (meaning that he was crying for a certain period of time in the past) (past perfect progressive). "He had cried at that time....." (past perfect).

Comment: In both cases, it is denoted to mean that that action happened before another even/action took place in the past.

Answer (score 2):

He was crying 'then' or he was crying 'at that time' seems to be the apt sentence.